# Horizontally center video in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, video, html5-video

Researched elsewhere, can't find a solution to horizontally center a video in a Bootstrap div / header section while keeping the video vertically aligned with the top. Div / header section is 100% width with two fixed heights at certain viewport breakpoints.

I've tried removing/renaming the `<header>` tag in case Bootstrap's styles interfere. Tried `<center>` tags, specifying the video tag as `display:inline` and many many other attempts.

The video in this example centers at certain breakpoints but otherwise is left-aligned. I'd like it to be centered throughout all viewport widths, and top aligned as well.

Thanks very much!

HTML:

```
<header>
  <video loop muted autoplay poster="images/3671960.jpg" class="fullscreen-video">
        <source src="video/3671960.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
<div class="header-content">
  <div class="header-content-inner">
      <h1>A bunch of header text.</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="launcher">
    <div class="launcher-inner">
      <a href="#what-i-do" class="btn btn-primary btn-outline-inverse page-scroll text-capitalize">Button text</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
header {
position: relative;
text-align: center;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width:100%;
height: 475px;
color: #fff;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0 auto;
}

header .fullscreen-video {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
min-width:100%;
min-height:100%;
z-index: -100;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) { 
header {
height: 665px;
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<header>
  <video loop muted autoplay poster="images/3671960.jpg" class="fullscreen-video">
    <source src="video/3671960.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
<div class="header-content">
  <div class="header-content-inner">
      <h1>A bunch of header text.</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="launcher">
    <div class="launcher-inner">
      <a href="#what-i-do" class="btn btn-primary btn-outline-inverse page-scroll text-capitalize">Button text</a>
    </div>
</div>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
header {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width:100%;
  height: 475px;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header .fullscreen-video {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  min-width:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  z-index: -100;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) { 
  header {
    height: 665px;
  }
}
```

[Demo Link : https://jsfiddle.net/hellosrini/vwc5hek0/](https://jsfiddle.net/hellosrini/vwc5hek0/)

Comment: This got me to the solution - thanks! Posting the final solution as an answer - see below.

Comment: lol this guy took your answer and then checked his own solution. jeez. i upvoted you @SrinivasanLakshmanan

Comment: Edited your answer to move the helpful css from `.test` class into the `header . fullscreen-video` class and marked it as correct. Thanks for the help!